# Do multi kills get less gold in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was on a killing spree and they killed me, however I was killed as part of a multi kill.

As you can see they got less gold than the norm (they got 273 instead of 300).

Has it been confirmed if this is a bug or intended feature?

[image: Source]

Answer (score 4):

Bounties change depending on how well the target is doing. A person on a 'dying streak' (i.e. consecutive deaths without any kills) is worth less with each death, whereas a person on a 'kill streak' increases in value.

Specific numbers are [here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Kill#Gold_reward).

Answer (score 0):

If you look it says + 273!

He got the kill (if not on deaths streak) of 300
+273!
Total 573

Conclusion. No they do give more.

Comment: I think what he is asking is why his death only gave a bonus of 273 while his teammate's death gave a bonus of 300.

Answer (score 0):

That's odd. Afaik "Bonus: XXX" is including the base kill value of 300 gold, and the only thing supposed to reduce kill value is if the victim has had several deaths in a row. 273 is the amount which is supposed to be awarded if you have died twice in a row, but according to the callouts you were actually on a killing spree, which should have awarded 363 gold or more.

I can't recall either of these being changed recently, so this seems like a bug.